# Fontawesome icon width 100% width vue fontawesome component

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome

We are using fontawesome in a vue project with the official [vue-fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome) component.

I want the icon to be adjusted to the width of the parent box (width=100%).

How to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i find a solution. I have to set `width:100%` AND `height:100%` or `height:auto;`

`<font-awesome-icon icon="blender-phone" style="width:100%; height:auto;"/>`